# Reversing the order of a nested loop without using extra memory

Tags: optimization, loops, for-loop, nested, algebra

I'm not sure if this is a math (algebra) question or a programming question.

I have a nested loop (in a shader program) that does something like this (L and B are read-only):

```
for each L in (L1, L2)
  Q=L
  for each B in (B1, B2, B3)
    Q *= B
  result += Q
```

So the result of this loop would be:

```
result += L1*B1*B2*B3 + L2*B1*B2*B3
```

This is the right result, **but access of B is slow and access of L is fast**.  So, iterating over the B's in the inner loop is considerably slower than iterating over L in the inner loop (I read each B *twice* in the above, and each L once).

If we naively reverse the inner/outer loop,

```
for each B in (B1, B2, B3)
  Q=B
  for each L in (L1, L2)
    Q *= L
  result += Q
```

Of course this result becomes

```
result += B1*L1*L2 + B2*L1*L2 + B3*L1*L2
```

I read each B once here, but this result is wrong.  I need products of the form `L1*B1*B2*B3`.  I know I can create an array `Q[2]` and just do:

```
for each L
  Q[i] = Li // save in array
```

Then iterate over B:

```
for each B in (B1, B2, B3)
  for i = 1..2
    Q[i] *= B

result += Q[i]
```

Which gives

```
result += Q[1]*B1*B2*B3 + Q[2]*B1*B2*B3
```

This is correct, but it is a "bit*" wasteful of memory if `L` is large (it is).  I'm wondering if I can do this algebraically without the intermediate `L[]` array.

<sub>* Pun intended</sub>

Answer (score 2):

A way that has no nested loop:

```
result = 0
for each L in (L1, L2)
  result += L
for each B in (B1, B2, B3)
  result *= B
```

because

`L1*B1*B2*B3 + L2*B1*B2*B3`

reduces to

`B1*B2*B3*(L1+L2)`

Comment: This would be really great, only I neglected to mention that B's relationship with each L has to be found first. Let me factor that in.

Answer (score 0):

I may be getting the question wrong wrong but isn't `L1*B1*B2*B3 + L2*B1*B2*B3` equal to `(L1+L2)*B1*B2*B3`?